# String manipulation question

Tags: c#, .net, string

If I have  this string:

```
D://MyDocuments/Pictures/Pic1.jpg
```

and I want to extract ".jpg" out of this string ie I want the (dot)(extension)

How do I go about it? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its can be done using substring but its better if you do it with Path.GetExtension

```
 string fileName = @"C:\mydir.old\myfile.ext";
 string path = @"C:\mydir.old\";
 string extension;

 extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at using [Path.GetExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or
>   null, or String.Empty. If path is null, GetExtension returns null. If
>   path does not have extension information, GetExtension returns
>   String.Empty.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the Path class to fetch the file information.

```
 Path.GetExtension("youpath")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath(@"D://MyDocuments/Pictures/Pic1.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 2):

For filenames, look into `System.IO.Path` [static members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).  You'll find plenty of methods there.

If you want to stick with string manipulation, something like this would be nice:

```
string wholeName = @"D:\MyDocuments\Pictures\Pic1.jpg";
int dotPosition = wholeName.LastIndexOf('.'); // find last dot
string ext = wholeName.Substring(dotPosition); // get out the extenstion
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use

```
string path = "D://MyDocuments/Pictures/Pic1.jpg";
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
```